# Altium error: Net contains multiple output sheet entries

Tags: schematics, altium, error

I'm having a hard time with this problem and cannot figure out how to deal with it. As shown in the figure below, ADC[0..2] is going out from A2 and A3 and in to A1:

[image]

In details:

- ADC 0 is the output of A2
- ADC 1 and ADC 2 are the outputs of A3

All three pins are inputs in A1, this connection seems to be logical, but Altium didn't like it!!

So the question is: How can I get multiple output sheet entries without Errors ?

Comment: A2 should only have a port called ADC0. A1 should only have ports labelled ADC1 and ADC2.

Comment: I want to make it as One BUS, not wires!

Comment: Using busses in Altium is so counter-intuitive and prone to this kind of error that I simply don't use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now you have two buses with same name, that is how Altium sees it, and it makes sense. ADC[0..2] on both sheets.
You can not make Output for bus containing 3 signals, from two different sheets. Your A2 sheet contains only one signal and A3 two signals, so solution is to make Bus entries at top level and connect those signals with outputs from sheets A2 and A3. You can name your signals as ADC 0, ADC 1, ADC 2. ADC 0 is output from A2 and is connected to the bus over bus entry, same is with ADC 1 and ADC 2. And input to A1 can be same as it is now.

Comment: Your solution proposal is not clear for me, could you please make it clearer !! what do you mean by "BUS entry at top level" and "connected to the bus over bus entry"?

Comment: Your output ports on sheet A2 and A3 should be named as ADC 0 (from A2) and two separate outputs from A3 name ADC 1 and ADC 2. Then use bus entries and place them (connect) to the bus you have now, and connect those output ports from A2 and A3 to those bus entries. On the sheet A1 you have input from the bus named ADC[0..2] and that is OK, because your bus is created from three signals ADC 0 from A2, ADC 1 and ADC 2 from A3.

Comment: Great, that works fine now !!